# Error building xcode project when i add a library with extension .a

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project and I need to add a static library with extension `.a` who sent me for integrated a functionality. I added the library in Build Phases - *Link Binary With Libraries*, but when I compile my project with this library I added, I does not compile and shows this error:

> could not parse object file /routelibrary/libraryname.a(IosHttp.o): 'Unknown attribute kind (45)Unknown attribute kind (45)Unknown attribute kind (45)', using libLTO version 'Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)' for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea on how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is missing `Other Linker Flags` in your target build settings.

First check if you need to set any `Other Linker Flags` in documentation of your static library, and if yes, what that flag is.

For example so many libraries needs `-ObjC` as `Other Linker Flags`.

To find `Other Linker Flags`, do following.

1. Select Build `Targets` in your Xcode project.
2. select `Build Settings`.
3. In Search Box type `Other Linker Flags`
4. check and set your flags here.